# Keycloak user session retention after restart

Tags: session, keycloak, quarkus, infinispan, retention

We are using keycloak 18 and we have not enabled ispn cache & now we have close to 15000 users sessions logged in to our application. To enable ispn cache we have to restart the instance and all 15k users sessions will be lost, is there a possibility that we can backup these sessions and restore them after the restart.

Any help would be much appreciated.

We tried to clone the keycloak instance and configured a infinispan server to persist the sessions into database, But when we manually add any new sessions to the client session table those sessions are not loaded back to keycloak on restart.

[client session table from infinispan cache server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOcr7.png)